# GUI framework recommandations for Python in 2020

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, wxpython

I'm trying to decide which GUI framework to use to build my first Python GUI desktop app.

Important to mention that I recently started coding in Python and **I do not have strong bases in C++**.
For now my main focus for python is data parsing and data analytics. I plan on learning more advanced machine learning skills by end of year. The first GUI I'd like to build is for my data parsing though, it would be pretty basic with a couple buttons to popup file selection dialogs, select destination folders and load a file containing a set of parsing parameters.

Since I still consider myself a beginner, so I will pay attention to:

1. available documentation
2. active/supportive community
3. simplicity to get started with coding the UI
4. simplicity of sharing UI (although I plan on compiling to exe, so this may not be such a pb?)

For these reasons, I'm leaning towards using built in TKinter or wxPython which appears to give a neater result and which comes with many different widgets. PyQT seemed more complicated to learn to begin with

I would however really welcome a GUI designer function where I can build a simple enough UI using my mouse like in PyQT though. Does wxPython offer something similar?

I also read good things about PySide & Kivy any thoughts ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recently come across the same issue and found another posting on here that may address what your looking for.

[Displaying Pandas dataframe in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057730/displaying-pandas-dataframe-in-tkinter)

From personal experience **tkinter** is my preferred module for creating GUI's. There is plenty of documentation online and customizable widgets that addresses the functionality your looking for. Considering your experience in Python, I recommend this to start.

As for data parsing, I recommend using the **pandas** module as well. The pandas library provides several methods that are helpful when parsing files. I've used this to parse large csv files in the past.

The posting above has a link to a YouTube video playlist from "sentdx" who use tkinter to create a GUI to report bitcoin analytics. He also addresses how to convert tkinter to exe as well.

Best of Luck

Comment: Thanks, I will check this out. Yes the overall concensus seems to be that TKinter is the easiest to learn with less overhead.

Answer (score 1):

You can try out Dash which is a Python-based framework which is predominantly used to create web applications that include intense data visualizations. For the purpose of data analytics and visualization this frame work could be better.
You can find out more information [here](https://medium.com/better-programming/build-an-interactive-modern-dashboard-using-dash-ab6b34cb515).